# How can I control GTK Windows from the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, window-manager

How can I select and perform actions on GTK Windows from the terminal? Specifically, I'd like close all windows whose title includes a certain string.

Usually, I just use `ps` to find the relevant process and then kill the process. However, I have a circumstance where multiple windows are sharing the same process and I don't want to kill the parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl) is the tool for interacting with the X Window manager from the terminal. To close all windows matching the string `$myStr`, use this:

```sh
while wmctrl -c "$myStr";do :;done
```

#### Explanation

wmctrl uses the -c parameter to close a window. Conveniently, this can do string matching on the window title as I was hoping for. However, wmctrl will only act on a single window at a time, so I loop to do this repeatedly until all matching windows are closed. When this happens, wmctrl returns an error code and stops looping. The ':' is a [no-op shell builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910) that is required since bash loops can't be empty.

You may need to install wmctrl first, eg. `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`